# NotXContentException when serializing Scala object to Json and indexing into Elasticsearch

Tags: json, scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I am attempting to index a relatively complex Scala object in Elasticsearch.  Here are my case classes:

```
case class Game(id: Int,
            gameStates: Seq[GameState],
            playerActions: Map[String, PlayerAction],
            gameActions: Map[String, GameAction],
            endGame: EndGame)
case class GameState(players: Seq[Player])
case class Player(id: Int, deck: Seq[Card], playSpace: Seq[Card])
case class Card (rank: Int, suit: String) extends Ordered[Card]
```

For each of these case classes I have a companion object that contains a definition for the Format[ObjectType] writes method in this style:

```
object Game {
  implicit object GameFormat extends Format[Game] {
    def writes(game: Game): JsValue = {
      Json.toJson(game.gameStates)
    }

    def reads(json:JsValue): JsResult[Game] = {
      //need this to satisfy compiler
      JsSuccess(Game(-1, Seq(), Map(), Map(), new EndGame("", (x: GameState) => None)))
    }
  }

  implicit object GameIndexable extends Indexable[Game] {
    override def json(game: Game): String =
      game.gameStates.map(x => Json.toJson(x).toString()).mkString(",")
  }
}
```

Here are my connection settings and method to perform the indexing:

```
val settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                    .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch_dan-dev").build()
val uri = ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://localhost:9300")
val esServer = ElasticClient.transport(settings, uri)

def sendGameToServer(game: Game) : Unit = {
  esServer.execute {
    index into "war" -> "games" source game
  }
}
```

When I run my app, I get the following exception from Elasticsearch when I try to index a Game object:

```
[2016-02-22 13:34:28,247][DEBUG][action.index             ] [dan_01_dev] failed to execute [index {[war][games][AVMK56uUwAlQMxc6Khfa], source[_na_]}] on [[war][1]]
MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: NotXContentException[Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes];
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseDocument(DocumentParser.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:304)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareCreate(IndexShard.java:500)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareCreateOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:481)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.prepareIndexOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:214)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:223)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:157)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:65)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:595)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:263)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:260)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:350)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.compress.NotXContentException: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes
    at org.elasticsearch.common.compress.CompressorFactory.compressor(CompressorFactory.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentHelper.createParser(XContentHelper.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseDocument(DocumentParser.java:99)
    ... 17 more
```

I'm having trouble finding info about this exception. I understand that it means my object isn't properly formatted to be indexed, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot beyond that.  I have confirmed that when I print out the Json rather than indexing it I have valid Json. Any ideas on why Elasticsearch doesn't like the Json I'm trying to index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GameIndexable` is invoking `.mkString(",")` on the result of your map, so you'd end up with a "json" string like:

`{ ... }, { ... }, { ... }`

Which isn't valid Json. If you want to index multiple game states, you'll need to make a bulk request, and each one containing a single game state.

Or if you wanted to index the `Game` object then your `GameIndexable` should be something like:

```
implicit object GameIndexable extends Indexable[Game] {
  override def json(game: Game): String = GameFormat.writes(game).toString
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @monkjack, that makes sense.  However I made that edit, recompiled, and am still getting the same NotXContentException.  For reference, here's a smaller JSon example I'm outputting which I believe is the exact same as the JSon I'm trying to index: `[[{"id":0,"deck":[{"rank":12,"suit":"♣"}],"playSpace":[]},{"id":1,"deck":[{"rank":2,"suit":"♣"}],"playSpace":[]}]]` Any reason I would be having trouble with that JSon?

Comment: It's a json array, not a json object. You need a json object as the output of your indexable.

Comment: Perfect, looks like I'm now indexing successfully!  For reference for others, here's how I edited my `GameFormat.writes` method to return a json object rather than an array: `def writes(game: Game): JsValue = {
      Json.toJson(
        Map("game" ->
          Json.toJson(game.gameStates)
        )
      )
    }`

Comment: You could probably do `def writes(game: Game): JsValue = Json.toJson(game.gameStates) }` to avoid having the "game" outer field

Comment: That's how I had my `writes` method before when it was returning an array rather than an object.  Is there something I can do to return that array as an object without the "game" field?  It would be nice to get rid of that outer field if I can.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write `def writes(game: Game): JsValue = Json.toJson(game) }`